# What does "with domain specs non-public dns" mean?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, configuration, dnsmasq

I am configuring DNSMASQ to utilize upstream nameservers without using `/etc/resolv.conf` with the `server=` option. What I don't quite understand is what `domain spec` mean in the following sentence?

dnsmasq.conf

```
# Add other name servers here, with domain specs if they are for
# non-public domains.
server=/localnet/10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an **optional** section the permits to specify forwarders for a specific domain.

You can put `server=8.8.8.8` in your config to specify a server for all domains.

If you want all google.com resolved by a specific server the do something like `server=/google.com/8.8.4.4`.

Comment: Ahh, I got it now. The explanation is too vague for me. Thanks